# JavaScript: What is the best way to load application environment variables at page initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm relatively new to JavaScript. One thing I'm trying to do is be able to have certain environment variables, specifically the hostname. In development, it'll be localhost. In production, it'll be completely different.

I've already seen how using a JSON file can be used to load values, as such:

value.json

```
{
    "myVal": "production"
}
```

JQuery $.getJSON() (part of an IIFE function that creates an object with immutable fields)

```
$.getJSON("value.json", function(data){
    myVal = data.myVal; //Not globally assigned, assigned to field in enclosing function
    console.log(data.myVal);
});
```

The problem is that getJSON() is asynchronous. While the amount of time to load that data is minimal, it does create a scenario where is is possible that a user could click on a link on the page before it finishes loading the hostname value.

I'm just wondering what the best way to handle this would be? How can I ensure that this value is always available?

One idea I've had so far is to use the session token, since it's already a part of the request/response mechanism, and will always be available. Since it will be a signed token, its values will be secure so someone won't be able to maliciously change those values.

But that sounds kind of like a hacky solution. So I'm wondering if there is a better, more elegant way to go about it?

Comment: Uhm, wouldn't the hostname always be available in `window.location.hostname` anyway? If you need serverside variables on the clientside, just output them in the markup and fetch them with JS.

Comment: @adeneo Thank you for letting me know that, as I said I'm relatively new to JavaScript. This will be my first full project using it. As for what you mean by outputting them in the markup, can you explain that more thoroughly?

Comment: Your server is sending the page anyway, so you can just add the data you need clientside to the page before it's sent from the server, you don't have to use ajax. See the answer below, which shows an example in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

An approach I often use is to import the variables from my backend.
For example if you are using PHP you could just `echo` out the variables.
You could place the following `<script>` in your `<head>` and the `CONFIG` will be available everywhere.

```
<script>
var CONFIG = {
  host: "<?php echo $host; ?>",
  otherConfig: "<?php echo $otherConfig; ?>"
};
</script>
```